# How to run an import in Marketing Cloud from a salesforce report with fields that contain commas

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, import

Marketing Cloud question:

I'm trying to import from a Salesforce report. Some of the records contain fields with commas e.g. 'English, Academic'.

When I run the report any records which contain commas fails to import. It says there is a 'Invalid field count'. It thinks that 'English' and 'Academic' are two separate fields.

Is there anyway to get around this problem? There are no options when importing or running to prevent this from happening.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the box for "Respect double quotes ( " ) as a text qualifier" in your import definition to make it work.

I just made a quick test to be sure and it worked fine. :)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your comment. I've also tried this but it's still coming up with errors. Perhaps there's a problem with our Marketing Cloud setup.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is facing the same problem. Try contacting MC Support. It took them over 3 weeks and 3 phone calls to realise and sort this out:

"*Out Internal Teams had to upgrade the Import version for your account. What this does is it improves the efficiency and performance of how import process works... this is a setting which can only be configured on the Marketing Cloud side I'm afraid.*"